# Local git repository showing no “current” branch

Tags: xcode, git

HyWhen trying to refactor storyboard, it seems I have accidentally broken local git. Now it didn’t show a “current” branch anymore. All the branches I have are still there. I can also branch from existing branches, but I can’t make new commit. There’s no “A” or “M” when I made changes to code. There is still the blue lines indicating where you made changes in code files. What do I need to do to get got to work?

Here’s how I come to this situation:

1. I tried to refactor Main.storyboard. Selected a few Controllers, Editor->Refactor to Storyboard
2. I didn’t check at the time, but I believe the “Where” was set to “Base.Iproj” by default.
3. The new storyboard ended up not in the right place. Since I can’t “undo” this refactoring, I deleted it.
4. Committed the two code files I modified, deselected the storyboards and another file I didn’t remember the name of and hit commit. Then I discarded all changes from “Source Control” menu.
5. This break the code. Build failed.
6. So I checked out the newly committed one, didn’t work.
7. I checked out the one before. This time the build was successful. However, git stopped working like I described above. No “current” on any branch, and when tried to commit, it didn’t show any error. It simply didn’t have any effect.
8. However, when I tried to commit, the refactored storyboard that I have deleted showed up in the selection window with a checkbox, inside that base.Iproj folder. But I have go into my project folder and checked, there is no such file in that folder.
   [image]

This is really not code related and all I did that broke git was listed above. I wonder what I have done so wrong that git is rewarding me with this maddening malfunction but more importantly, I need the local repository to work. Appreciate any help.

I’m using Xcode 10.2. I have tried restarting the Mac, XCode, and the project. None worked.

Comment: Just checkout any branch?

Comment: @RomainValeri yes that solved it! It was driving me mad... I feel silly but also grateful. Thank you!

Comment: @RomainValeri btw do you know how to get rid of the storyboard file in the second pic that doesn’t actually exist? It’s probably not important but it’s just bugging me.

Comment: @Anthonia Sorry but I have no idea :-)

Comment: @RomainValeri no problem:)